# Why are the Input fields in my payment method all disabled

Tags: onepage-checkout, upgrade, payment-methods

During the process of testing a new Payment module I run into the problem, that all input fields of this module were disabled.

Apparently this happens as part of the payment.init() function of magento.

Why does Magento do this, and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disabling fields cause them to not get submitted via post.
This is primary to avoid overwrite of values by conflicting input names, which should not happen anyway by clean written modules. (most modules use the payment method code as prefix for input names to avoid this)

To the question: magento generally disables by default all input fields, which are not part of the method switching inputs.
It reactivates them during the `payment.switchMethod('payment_code')` for the current paymentmethod "form".

So if you have disabled input fields in the currently chosen payment method, it is likely that you removed the switchMethod call in your template.

there also seems to be a bug related to IE9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5371919/716029

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on method payment.init()

You will find the below code at the `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js`

`var Payment = Class.create();` payment class

```
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]') {
        if (elements[i].checked) {
            method = elements[i].value;
        }
    } else {
        elements[i].disabled = true;
    }
    elements[i].setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
}
```

so, all fields will be *disabled*

but can add some functions after **payment.init**

can add following JS-code - using **payment.addAfterInitFunction**

```
payment.addAfterInitFunction('setnotdisableinput', function () {
    if (document.getElementById("your-comment")) {
        document.getElementById("your-comment").disabled = false;
    }
});
```

so, now your input not disabled, available for edit :)